# prove Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that in a finite-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. The theorem states that each bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence.
Of course I know the prove with Kantor's lemma but I was asked to prove it 
by proving the lemma :  each bounded sequence has monotonic subsequence.
I'll be gratfull for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $M$ is the least upper bound for the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, if $x_{n}=M$ for infinitely many $n$'s, then choose this subsequence. Assume now without loss of generality that $x_{n}\ne M$ for every $n$, then we can find some $x_{n_{1}}$ such that $M-1<x_{n_{1}}<M$. We can then find some $x_{n_{2}}$ such that $\max\{M-1/2,x_{n_{1}}\}<x_{n_{2}}<M$. Proceed in this way we get the strictly increasing sequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ and that $M-1/k<x_{n_{k}}<M$, so the subsequence converges to $M$.